# RTSP get video from IP Camera with Erlang

Tags: erlang, rtsp

Trying to find any examples of how to get video from IP Camera via RTSP and record it on disk with Erlang. Is there any examples or manuals? Where to start to develop this functionality? For me isn't clear the global mechanism of interacting with camera.

The things that found by is:

- example of RTSP from erlyvideo that is very outdated https://github.com/erlyvideo/publisher/blob/master/apps/rtsp/src/rtsp.erl
- [erlang: how to receive HTTP/RTSP messages from socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534748/erlang-how-to-receive-http-rtsp-messages-from-socket)

When trying to connect via Telnet:

```
PLAY rtsp://192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0
Authorization: Basic *************=

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 0
Range: npt=0.000-
Session: 00000000
RTP-Info:
```

But video stream not appearing. What is missing by me?

The Erlang ode for connecting to IP Camera looks like:

```
get_rtsp() ->
    {ok,Socket} = gen_tcp:connect("192.168.*.*",554,[binary, {packet, line}]),
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, "OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.*.*:554 RTSP/1.0\r\n\r\n"),
    rtsp_data(Socket, []).
rtsp_data(Socket, SoFar) ->
    receive
        {tcp,Socket,Bin} ->
            erlang:display(is_binary(Bin)),
            erlang:display("Bin"),
            erlang:display(Bin),
            <<"RTSP/1.0 200 OK\r\n">> = Bin,
            rtsp_data(Socket, [Bin|SoFar]);
        {tcp_closed,Socket} ->
            erlang:display("SoFar"),
            erlang:display(SoFar)
    end.
```

The DESCRIBE of IP Camera looks like:

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.*.*:554 RTSP/1.0
Authorization: Basic *************=

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 0
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 390

v=0
o=- 1693921639435130 1 IN IP4 0
s=brovtech
t=0 0
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=recvonly
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:5000
a=control:track1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d002a;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AKpWoHgCJ+WbgICAgQA==,aO48gA==
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=control:track2
```

When trying to use SETUP command - just closing connection without any reason:

```
SETUP rtsp://192.168.*.*:554 RTSP/1.0
Authorization: Basic *************=

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

OPTIONS command reply looks like:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 0
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, SET_PARAMETER
```

Comment: I think you have to debug in the "erlyvideo" project by adding logs and read the project's  log file, then find why. The project is developed user R16, maybe some problem are created by erlang's version change. https://github.com/membraneframework/membrane_rtsp , this is elixir project and it may be more helpful.

Comment: github.com/membraneframework/membrane_rtsp , this is elixir project and it may be more helpful. @Chen Yu - Thx a lot. Never heard of this project. Will look on it today.

Answer (score 1):

For now problem with RTSP messages solved. Based on reference https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt and CURL-RTSP example application https://github.com/Akagi201/curl-rtsp made all of messages working with Erlang:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
Authorization: Basic **************=

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, SET_PARAMETER

DESCRIBE rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
Accept: application/sdp
Authorization: Basic **************=

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 390

v=0
o=- 1694003440986752 1 IN IP4 0
s=brovtech
t=0 0
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=recvonly
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:5000
a=control:track1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d002a;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AKpWoHgCJ+WbgICAgQA==,aO48gA==
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=control:track2

SETUP rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main/track2 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=1234-1235
Authorization: Basic **************=

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=1234-1235;server_port=34659-34660
Session: 1b50a95a

PLAY rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
Session: 1b50a95a
Range: 0.000-
Authorization: Basic **************=

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Range: npt=0.000-
Session: 1b50a95a
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main/track2;seq=49593;rtptime=1278180033
```

But still don't know where and how to get video stream from IP Camera. Based on RFC reference, RTSP server is kind of remote control of the camera. How to get video stream based on data from RTSP messages? Should be camera sending data to server or server should be getting data from camera?

Could someone explain of how RTSP camera is working in general? In my camera available ports TCP, RTSP, HTTP. Where should be appearing video stream? What should be done after getting 200 OK status for PLAY command?

Updated:

Found the OpenRTSP (http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/) application that is showing whole log of interaction with IP Camera.

```
$ openRTSP rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main
Created new TCP socket 3 for connection
Connecting to 192.168.*.*, port 554 on socket 3...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2023.07.24)


Received 93 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, SET_PARAMETER


Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2023.07.24)
Accept: application/sdp


Received 86 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
RTSP/1.0 401 Authorization Required
CSeq: 3
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="RTSP"


Resending...
Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
Authorization: Basic ****************************=
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2023.07.24)
Accept: application/sdp


Received 470 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 390

v=0
o=- 1694017411868114 1 IN IP4 0
s=brovtech
t=0 0
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=recvonly
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:5000
a=control:track1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d002a;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AKpWoHgCJ+WbgICAgQA==,aO48gA==
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=control:track2

Opened URL "rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main", returning a SDP description:
v=0
o=- 1694017411868114 1 IN IP4 0
s=brovtech
t=0 0
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=recvonly
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:5000
a=control:track1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d002a;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AKpWoHgCJ+WbgICAgQA==,aO48gA==
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=control:track2

Created receiver for "video/H264" subsession (client ports 54468-54469)
Created receiver for "audio/PCMA" subsession (client ports 49248-49249)
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main/track1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
Authorization: Basic ****************************=
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2023.07.24)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=54468-54469


Received 123 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 5
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=54468-54469;server_port=38510-38511
Session: 4fca269b


Setup "video/H264" subsession (client ports 54468-54469)
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main/track2 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 6
Authorization: Basic ****************************=
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2023.07.24)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=49248-49249
Session: 4fca269b


Received 123 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 6
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=49248-49249;server_port=31985-31986
Session: 4fca269b


Setup "audio/PCMA" subsession (client ports 49248-49249)
Created output file: "video-H264-1"
Created output file: "audio-PCMA-2"
Sending request: PLAY rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
Authorization: Basic ****************************=
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2023.07.24)
Session: 4fca269b
Range: npt=0.000-


Received 255 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete PLAY response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 7
Range: npt=0.000-
Session: 4fca269b
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main/track1;seq=38244;rtptime=393853382,url=rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main/track2;seq=31624;rtptime=723537895


Started playing session
Receiving streamed data (signal with "kill -HUP 4761" or "kill -USR1 4761" to terminate)...
^OGot shutdown signal
Sending request: TEARDOWN rtsp://user:pass@192.168.*.*:554/live/main RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 8
Authorization: Basic ****************************=
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2023.07.24)
Session: 4fca269b
```

Based on this log, there are need to create some kind of receivers for audio and video. How to do them? Is it just TCP listener?